# get set fields have stopped working

Tags: apex, visualforce

Get and set methods have stopped working after I customized my page with Bootstrap validator. This was working fine until this morning. I have now also tried removing all  and bootstrap JS libraries but cant get this to work. Based on debugs, my controller is unable to receive the values passed from VF page and getting null values upon save.

```
   <apex:page standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false"  controller="ContractorEnrolmentController">
<apex:messages />
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Contractor Entrollment Step1</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.2/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>




    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Image and text -->
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                <apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.pagelogo}" width="100%" alt="Description of image here" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Form Start  -->

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 margin-top30">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled multi-steps">
                        <li class="is-active" id="comp_info">
                            <p>Company Info</p>
                        </li>
                        <li id="business_info">
                            <p>Business</p>
                        </li>
                        <li id="business_owner_info">
                            <p>Business Owner</p>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-body"><p>We are excited for the opportunity to assist you with your material purchasing needs!</p>
                                                        <p>Please complete the form below,so that we can continue the enrollment process.</p></div>
                    </div>


                    <!-- Company Section  Start-->
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h2 class="panel-title">
                                Company
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body  margin-top10">
                            <form id="profileForm">
                                <apex:form >
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                                            <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control name" value="{!cmpFirstName}" id="fname" required="true" disabled="true"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                                            <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control name" id="lname" value="{!cmpLastName}" required="true" disabled="true"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                                            <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control" id="phone" value="{!cmpPhone}" html-name="phone" required="true" maxlength="10" disabled="true"/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                                            <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control email" id="email" value="{!cmpEmail}" html-name="email" disabled="true"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </apex:form>
                            </form>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <!-- Company Section  End-->
                    <!-- Business Section  Start-->
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                Business
                            </h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body margin-top10">
                            <form id="profileForm">
                                <apex:form >
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <label for="lbn">Legal Business Name</label>
                                        <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control name" id="lbn" value="{!buLegalBusinessName}" required="true"/>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="dba">DBA</label>
                                        <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control name" id="dba" value="{!buDBA}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="taxid">Tax ID</label>
                                        <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control taxid" id="taxid" onblur="myTaxId();" required="true" maxlength="11" value="{!buTaxId}"/>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="bphone">Phone</label>
                                        <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control" id="bphone" required="true" onblur=" myPhone() " maxlength="13" value="{!buPhone}"/ >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="bemail">Email</label>
                                        <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control email" id="bemail" required="true" value="{!cmpEmail}"/>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <label for="addr">Address</label>
                                        <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control address" id="addr" required="true" value="{!buAddr}"/>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        <label for="city">City</label>
                                        <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control name" id="city" required="true" value="{!buCity}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        <label for="state">State</label>
                                        <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control name" id="state" required="true" value="{!buState}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                        <label for="zip">Zip</label>
                                        <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control zipcode" id="zip" required="true" maxlength="6"  value="{!buZip}" />
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                        <label for="noemp">Number of Employees</label>
                                        <apex:selectList styleclass="form-control" multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!buNoofemp}">
                                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="1-10" itemValue="1-10" />
                                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="10-25" itemValue="10-25" />
                                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="25-50" itemValue="25-50" />
                                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="50-100" itemValue="50-100" />
                                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="100-500" itemValue="100-500" />
                                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="500-1000" itemValue="500-1000" />
                                            <apex:selectOption itemLabel="1000+" itemValue="1000+" />
                                        </apex:selectList>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="avgprjamt">Average Project Amount</label>
                                        <span class="currency" style="display: none">$</span>
                                        <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control avgprjamt" id="avgprjamt" required="true" value="{!buAvgPrjAmt}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="annrev">Annual Revenue</label>
                                        <span class="currency-annrev" style="display: none">$</span>
                                        <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control annrev" id="annrev" required="true" value="{!buAnnRev}"/>
                                    </div>

                                </apex:form>
                            </form>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <!-- Business Section  End-->


                    <!-- Business Owner Section  Start-->
                    <div class="panel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">
                                Business Owner
                            </h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body margin-top30">
                            <form id="profileForm">
                                <apex:form >

                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="ofname">Owner First Name</label>
                                        <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control name" id="ofname" required="true" value="{!boFirstName}"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="olname">Owner Last Name</label>
                                        <apex:inputText styleclass="form-control name" id="olname" required="true" value="{!boLastName}"/>
                                    </div>



                                </apex:form>
                            </form>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <!-- Business Owner Section  End-->
                                <apex:form >
                    <apex:commandbutton id="submit" value="Next" action="{!step2}" styleclass="btn btn-info btn-md register-btn" style="color: #fff;
                                                        padding:8px;
                                                        width: 30%;
                                                        display: block;
                                                        background: none;
                                                        background-color: #0099de;
                                                        font-size: 14px;
                                                        float:right;" /> 


                                </apex:form> 


                </div>

            </div>

        </div>



        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.2/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#datepicker').datepicker();
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("<style type='text/css' id='dynamic' />").appendTo("head");
                $("#comp_info").addClass("is-active");
                 $("#dynamic").html(".multi-steps > li#comp_info.is-active:before{background-color:#0099de;border-color:#0099de; color:#fff;}");
                  $("li.is-active p").css("color", "#0099de");
                $('[id$=":fname"]').trigger('click');
                $('[id$=":fname"]').click(function () {
                    $("#business_owner_info").removeClass("is-active");
                    $("#business_info").removeClass("is-active");
                    $("#comp_info").addClass("is-active");
                    $('ul.list-unstyled > li > P').css("color", "");
                    $("li.is-active p").css("color", "#0099de");
                    $("#dynamic").html(".multi-steps > li#comp_info.is-active:before{background-color:#0099de;border-color:#0099de; color:#fff;}");
                });

                $('[id$=":lbn"]').click(function () {
                    $("li.is-active p").css("color", "");
                    $("#comp_info").removeClass("is-active");
                    $("#business_info").removeClass("is-active");
                    $("#business_info").addClass("is-active");
                    $('ul.list-unstyled > li > P').css("color", "");
                    $("li.is-active p").css("color", "#0099de");
                    $("#dynamic").html(".multi-steps > li#business_info.is-active:before{background-color:#0099de;border-color:#0099de; color:#fff;}.multi-steps > li#comp_info:after {    background-color: #0099de;    }");
                });

                $('[id$=":ofname"]').click(function () {
                    $("li.is-active p").css("color", "");
                    $("#comp_info").removeClass("is-active");
                    $("#business_info").removeClass("is-active");
                    $("#business_owner_info").addClass("is-active");
                   $('ul.list-unstyled > li > P').css("color", "");
                    $("li.is-active p").css("color", "#0099de");
                    $("#dynamic").html(".multi-steps > li#business_owner_info.is-active:before{background-color:#0099de;border-color:#0099de; color:#fff;}.multi-steps > li#business_info:after {    background-color: #0099de;     }");
                });

            });
        </script>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('<span style="color: #FF0000;font-size:14px;">*</span>').insertBefore('[required]');
                $('#profileForm').bootstrapValidator({
                    feedbackIcons: {

                        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                    },
                    fields: {
                        name: {
                            selector: ".name",
                            message: "Name is required",
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: "Please provide Name"
                                },

                                regexp: {
                                    regexp: /^[A-Za-z ]+$/,
                                    message: 'The full name can consist of alphabetical characters and spaces only'
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        phone: {
                            selector: ".phone",
                            country: 'US',
                            message: "Phone number is required",
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: "Please provide Phone number"
                                },

                                regexp: {
                                    regexp: /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-.●]?([0-9]{3})[-.●]?([0-9]{4})$/,
                                    message: 'Please enter valid Phone number'
                                }

                            }
                        },
                        email: {
                            selector: ".email",
                            message: "Email address is required",
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: "Please provide Email"
                                },

                                regexp: {
                                    regexp: /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
                                    message: 'Please enter valid email'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        taxid: {
                            selector: ".taxid",
                            message: "Tax ID is required",
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: "Please provide Tax ID"
                                },

                                regexp: {
                                    regexp: /^[0-9]*$/,
                                    message: 'Please enter valid Tax ID'
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        zipcode: {
                            selector: ".zipcode",
                            message: "valid Zipcode is required",
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: "Please provide Zipcode"
                                },

                                regexp: {
                                    regexp: /^[0-9]*$/,
                                    message: 'Enter valid Zipcode'
                                }

                            }
                        }


                    }
                });

            });


        </script>


        <script>
            function mySSN() {

                var patt = new RegExp("\d{3}[\-]\d{2}[\-]\d{4}");
                var x = document.getElementById('myPage1:j_id33:ossn');
                var res = patt.test(x.value);

                if (!res) {
                    x.value = x.value
                        .match(/\d*/g).join('')
                        .match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,4})/).slice(1).join('-')
                        .replace(/-*$/g, '');
                }
            }

            function myTaxId() {
                var patt = new RegExp("\d{2}[\-]\d{7}");
                var x = document.getElementById('myPage1:j_id10:taxid');

                var res = patt.test(x.value);
                if (!res) {
                    x.value = x.value
                        .match(/\d*/g).join('')
                        .match(/(\d{0,2})(\d{0,7})/).slice(1).join('-')
                        .replace(/-*$/g, '');
                }
            }






        </script>

<script>
        (function ($, undefined) {

            "use strict";

            // When ready.
            $(function () {

                var $form = $('#profileForm');
               var $input = $form.find('#avgprjamt');

               jQuery("input[id$='avgprjamt']").keyup(function () {
                $(".currency").css("display","block");
                $("input[id$='avgprjamt']").css("padding-left","35px");
                    // When user select text in the document, also abort.

                    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
                    if (selection !== '') {
                        return;
                    }

                    // When the arrow keys are pressed, abort.
                    if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, [38, 40, 37, 39]) !== -1) {
                        return;
                    }


                    var $this = $(this);

                    // Get the value.
                    var input = $this.val();

                    var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "");
                    input = input ? parseInt(input, 10) : 0;

                    $this.val(function () {
                        return (input === 0) ? "" : input.toLocaleString("en-US");
                    });
                    if($("input[id$='avgprjamt']").val() == ''){
                    $(".currency").css("display","none");
                    $("input[id$='avgprjamt']").css("padding-left","10px");
   }
                });




            });
        })(jQuery);


    </script>
    <script>
        (function ($, undefined) {

            "use strict";

            // When ready.
            $(function () {

                var $form = $('#profileForm');
               var $input = $form.find('#annrev');

               jQuery("input[id$='annrev']").keyup(function () {
                $(".currency-annrev").css("display","block");
                $("input[id$='annrev']").css("padding-left","35px");
                    // When user select text in the document, also abort.

                    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
                    if (selection !== '') {
                        return;
                    }

                    // When the arrow keys are pressed, abort.
                    if ($.inArray(event.keyCode, [38, 40, 37, 39]) !== -1) {
                        return;
                    }


                    var $this = $(this);

                    // Get the value.
                    var input = $this.val();

                    var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "");
                    input = input ? parseInt(input, 10) : 0;

                    $this.val(function () {
                        return (input === 0) ? "" : input.toLocaleString("en-US");
                    });
                    if($("input[id$='annrev']").val() == ''){
                    $(".currency-annrev").css("display","none");
                    $("input[id$='annrev']").css("padding-left","10px");
   }
                });




            });
        })(jQuery);


    </script>


    </body>


    </html>


</apex:page>
```

Get Set Variables

```
       Public String myName {get; Set;}  
public string signerName {get; set;}
public String cmpFirstName {get; set;}
public String cmpLastName {get; set;}
public String cmpPhone {get; set;}
public String cmpEmail {get; set;}
public id contactid {get; set;}
public id accountid {get; set;}

/* public String buLegalBusinessName {get; set { buLegalBusinessName = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } } */
public String buLegalBusinessName {get; set; } 
public String buDBA {get; set; }
public String buTaxId {get; set; }
public String buPhone {get; set; }
public String buEmail {get; set; }
public String buAddr {get; set; }
public String buCity {get; set; }
```

Comment: you might check out the page markup as the source of your trouble, where you've got issues like nested form tags `<div class="panel-body margin-top10"> <form id="profileForm"> <apex:form >`

Comment: Thanks Mark. I tried that but still running into same issue. I removed  <div class="panel-body margin-top10"> <form id="profileForm"> <apex:form > . Any other suggestions? Also, do HTML tag interfere with APEX get set methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your HTML is the source of your problem. The getters and setters are fine.

As an example, the first step of your UI contains a `form` with just one `button` inside it. This form tag does not contain any of the fields shown and filled in by the user. Clicking the 'Next' button submits its parent `form`... but this form post does not contain any data (the input fields), only the button itself.

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:commandbutton id="submit" value="Next" action="{!step2}" styleclass="btn btn-info btn-md register-btn" style="color: #fff;
                                        padding:8px;
                                        width: 30%;
                                        display: block;
                                        background: none;
                                        background-color: #0099de;
                                        font-size: 14px;
                                        float:right;" /> 


</apex:form>
```

I would recommend removing all of the `form` tags within the page body and simplify your page by wrapping your page body contents in one `<apex:form> </apex:form>` tag.

Additionally, you've got `html`, `head` and `body` tags in your markup and should add the `applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false"` attributes to the `<apex:page>` tag to ensure Salesforce doesn't render extra tags, creating invalid markup.

Comment: Thank you Mark, most helpful. This gives me a working version of my page. One last question, removing  <form id="profileForm"> has broken my page and validation are not working anymore.  I had multiple <Form> Tags for a reason. How do I go about fixing it? Can I replace them with multiple <apex:form>s. Much appreciate your help.

Comment: Hard to fix your form for you but that isn't working because the JS is looking for an element with that id (`var $form = $('#profileForm');`) You will need to adjust the script to locate the elements. If you need to dynamically get the DOM id of the element for that selector you can use the [$Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm) global function. This change could make your script look like this instead: `var $form = $("[id='$Component.MyPage.profileForm']");` assuming you put an id on the page tag of MyPage too.